# the problem of swift-container-replicator on openstack swift

Tags: openstack-swift

```
root@storage2:/var/log/swift# service swift-container-replicator status
● swift-container-replicator.service - OpenStack Swift container replicator
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/swift-container-replicator.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-11-23 00:48:32 UTC; 22min ago
       Docs: man:swift-container-replicator(1)
   Main PID: 283739 (swift-container)
      Tasks: 23 (limit: 76605)
     Memory: 52.5G
     CGroup: /system.slice/swift-container-replicator.service
             ├─283739 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/swift-container-replicator /etc/swift/container-server.conf
             ├─283945 rsync --quiet --no-motd --timeout=10 --contimeout=1 --whole-file /srv/node/sde/containers/1375/86c/55f2cbefdd2bad9e9a3e6160b5d1c86c/55f2cbefdd2bad9e9a3e6160b5d1c86c.db 192.168.3.33::container/sdb/tmp/6a5d7016-a871-4d07-9c58-3fd58559b1f1
             └─284825 rsync --quiet --no-motd --timeout=10 --contimeout=1 --whole-file /srv/node/sdg/containers/319/62d/13f356b429d9719b6484587bfaf7862d/13f356b429d9719b6484587bfaf7862d.db 192.168.3.33::container/sdi/tmp/b94bff66-4b76-42b0-b913-a3b786eb3cb7

Nov 23 00:48:32 storage2 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenStack Swift container replicator.
Nov 23 00:48:32 storage2 systemd[1]: swift-container-replicator.service: Found left-over process 4098989 (rsync) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Nov 23 00:48:32 storage2 systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Nov 23 00:48:32 storage2 systemd[1]: swift-container-replicator.service: Found left-over process 4168060 (rsync) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Nov 23 00:48:32 storage2 systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Nov 23 00:48:32 storage2 systemd[1]: Started OpenStack Swift container replicator.
Nov 23 00:48:33 storage2 container-replicator[283739]: Starting 283739
Nov 23 00:48:57 storage2 container-replicator[283739]: Beginning replication run
```

```
root@storage2:/var/log/swift# swift-account-audit AUTH_7c94445c97c84aaba46d65652e82cc4f
Auditing account "AUTH_7c94445c97c84aaba46d65652e82cc4f"
Auditing container "qwy2"
Auditing container "test"
Auditing container "qwy"
  Bad status GETting container "/AUTH_7c94445c97c84aaba46d65652e82cc4f/qwy" on 192.168.3.33/sdi
  Bad status GETting container "/AUTH_7c94445c97c84aaba46d65652e82cc4f/qwy2" on 192.168.3.33/sdb
  Bad status GETting container "/AUTH_7c94445c97c84aaba46d65652e82cc4f/qwy" on 192.168.3.31/sdi
  Bad status GETting container "/AUTH_7c94445c97c84aaba46d65652e82cc4f/qwy2" on 192.168.3.31/sdg
```

After the db file is copied to the temporary directory of the specified server, there is no next step. I want to know which service is stuck.
How do I deal with the problem of missing container database files?